# Unlock Partition on Linux

Tags: boot, drivers, partitioning, windows-10, unlock

I locked a partition in my past OS (Windows 10), then I moved to Linux (Ubuntu) but I forgot to unlock the partition, So How can I unlock this?

Comment: How did you "lock" it?  If you used LUKS encryption, you need to provide proper authentication, otherwise you will not be able to decrypt.

Comment: The same for Bitlocker (Windows) if that was what you used (very likely). Of course you'll need Windows.